# I use variables in different php files without using session_start(). What am I missing about session_start() and when should I use this function?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP. I am doing a little project (where I read data, a password, from a database) to learn PHP and I am using some variables that I obtain in a form in different PHP files. I thought I should use session_start() and the global variable $_SESSION to use the same variables in different PHP files. Below it is my code, I have this files in one folder: index.php(HTML and forms), conn.php(connection to the database), login.php (file where I read data from database)

Can someone explain to me why I don't need to use session_start() in this case and in what specific situations I need to use the global variable $_SESSION?

index.php:

```
<?php
include_once "conn.php";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <form id="login" method="POST" action="login.php">
        <label for="loginUsername">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername">
        <br>
        <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

conn.php:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "loginsystem";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

login.php:

```
<?php
    include_once "conn.php";


    if(isset($_POST["login"])){

        $username = $_POST["loginUsername"];
        $password = $_POST["loginPassword"];

        echo $password;
        $sql = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?;";

        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $username);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row["password"];
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just a tip should go build further on this: DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS.
So how do you do that instead: 1. Store a one-way hash, never the password;  2. use a random salt to prevent rainbow table attacks; 3. use a slow hash algorithm or it's all in vain  more here: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am aware that I shouldnt store the passwords of the users in a database. For my little project that I doing to learn php I encrypt the passwords using the function "password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);", is this function in line with what you said or do I need use other functions to store the password on my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need sessions to use a variable in different php files. However you can use sessions to store and access data from different requests.

It could be the next step in your project. After a user logs in, she might be authorized to do . You don't want her to login for every task. So you need a way to allow her to perform those tasks without transmitting her password again.

This is an example where sessions could help you (or you could solve it in a different way).

But for the code you have now you don't need a session, it's fine as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am aware that I need use sessions to keep the user logged in after login validation, but I dont have for now a clear idea how I should use it. Should I for example store the password that user inserted on a form in a session variable and store the password that I get from the database in other session variable and compare those two variables every time its needed validate an action or should I use the session variables in a different way?

Comment: You would not store passwords. In a perfect world you would only store an ID in the `$_SESSION` variable, and PHP handles the rest. But sadly the world is not perfect, and there's something called "cross site request forgery". And to prevent that you need to remember something like a passcode/token/nonce and use it to validate any action. This token could be stored in a session and verified when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use session_start in the first place,you can only use $ _SESSION variable after session_start
I recommend you write the first line of config.php.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly you are wondering why you can access variables from one script in an other script.

The answer is simple: whenever you call `include` or `require`, everything in your included code - all variables and methods - are available in the caller script. This means that every single line of code of the included script is executed in the caller script.

This means that you have to be carefully how you handle includes: if you define a function in a script and include the script twice, PHP will throw an error where it says that the function with this name is already defined. To avoid this, you can use `include_once` or `require_once`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But for example in my case, I include the conn.php file on my main file (index.php) so I can use the connection, but I dont include the login.php file on my index.php where I define my variables in my form, but even so I can use those variables in login.php. In this case is the action="login.php" working as an include?

Comment: is login.php included everywhere else? what does login.php in `action="login.php"` call?

Comment: login.php isnt included anywhere, the action="login.php" go to database and see if the user exists and if the password is valid

Comment: are the contents of the variables that are available in index.php the same as of those from login.php? PHP does not care about declaration of variables. You can still use not declared variables.